# Preg_match gets me the content of entire page instead of a specific div

Tags: php, regex

Even though that I am trying to get only the content of the

```
<div class="description">...</div>
```

it returns me everything below this specific div. How can I get only the content between it?

```
$file_string = file_get_contents('');

preg_match('/<div class="description">(.*)<\/div>/si', $file_string, $description);
$description_out = $description[1];

echo $description_out;
```

Comment: I'd advise you to use something like [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) instead of regex - it's easier to use and more memory efficient.

Comment: Or, rather then adding an extra layer of abstraction, just parse the html with `DOMDocument` or the likes

Answer (score 2):

You should use [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) matching. Change the `(.*)` to `(.*?)`.

Also, try to avoid using regular expressions to parse HTML if possible.

Comment: @JohnBilly to expand upon Mark's answer, you should use the DOM http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php to parse your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method , indicated when you want to get /read HTML elements in PHP, using the PHP DOMDocument class.

```
<?php
// string with HTML content
$strhtml = '<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Document Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="dv1">www.MarPlo.net</div>
 <div class="description">http://www.coursesweb.net</div>
</body></html>';

// create the DOMDocument object, and load HTML from a string
$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
$dochtml->loadHTML($strhtml);

// gets all DIVs
$divs = $dochtml->getElementsByTagName('div');

// traverse the object with all DIVs
foreach($divs as $div) {
  // if the current $div has class="description", gets and outputs content
  if($div->hasAttribute('class') && $div->getAttribute('class') == 'description') {
    $cnt = $div->nodeValue;
    echo $cnt. '<br/>';
  }
}
?>
```

You can find documentation about DOMDocument on the php.net.